# Checking if a video is age restricted

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, discord, discord.py, youtube-data-api

Hello how am I able to search for video attributes to check if a video is an age-restricted and if it is then it launches an if statement

```
@commands.command()
    async def yt(self, ctx, *, search):
        query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
        htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
        search_results = re.findall(r'/watch\?v=(.{11})',htm_content.read().decode())
        await ctx.send('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])
```

A little backstory: I submitted my bot to top.gg which is a bot hosting site and it got declined because the bot was able to send "NSFW" content in non NSFW channels, I really want to get with working so all help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

According to YouTube's Data API docs, you have at your disposal the following property attached to age-restricted videos:

> [`contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating) (string)
>
> A rating that YouTube uses to identify age-restricted content.
>
> Valid values for this property are:
>
> - `ytAgeRestricted`

You'll have to invoke the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint, passing to it the parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) as `id=VIDEO_ID`, where `VIDEO_ID` is the ID of the video of your interest. Also need not forget to have the parameter [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) containing the value `contentDetails`.

The JSON response text will contain the value you need at `items[0].contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating`; that value should be checked if equals with `ytAgeRestricted`. Note also that the property `ytRating` may well be absent; in this case the video is not age-restricted.

---

In the context of Python, if you're using the [Google APIs Client Library for Python](http://github.com/google/google-api-python-client), then your call to the `Videos.list` endpoint would look like:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey = APP_KEY)

response = youtube.videos().list(
    id = VIDEO_ID,
    part = 'contentDetails',
    fields = 'items(contentDetails(contentRating(ytRating)))',
    maxResults = 1
).execute()

age_restricted = response['items'][0] \
    ['contentDetails'] \
    ['contentRating'] \
    .get('ytRating') == \
    'ytAgeRestricted'
```

Note that the code above is simplified quite much since there's no error handling.

Also note that the code above is using the parameter [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) for to obtain from the endpoint *only* the `ytRating` property. It's always good to ask from the API only the info that is really needed.